# How do I create Nested Change Listeners in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, nested, listener

I have a problem when I try to nest a couple of Change Listeners. I want to have a list of items in a table and when I select one of them, it brings up a number of options based on what was selected. I want to be able to move through the upper list selecting items individually not cumulative. However with the code below, when I select the nested listener I get multiple replies based on the number of times that I have selected an item in the first list. If I select one item, everything seems to work as expected but if I go to a different item then I get multiple results even though it gives me the correct results. Here is the Controller code.

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class HelloController {
    private ObservableList<ProductItem> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<OptionItem> optionData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private TableView itemListView;
    @FXML
    private TableView optionView;

    public void initialize(){
        String item = "";
        String id = "";
        ProductItem productItem = new ProductItem(item, id);
        productItem = new ProductItem("item1", "001");
        masterData.add(productItem);
        productItem = new ProductItem("item2", "002");
        masterData.add(productItem);
        productItem = new ProductItem("item3", "003");
        masterData.add(productItem);

        itemListView.getItems().setAll(masterData);

        itemListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ProductItem>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ProductItem> observableValue, ProductItem productItem, ProductItem newValue) {
                ProductItem item = (ProductItem) itemListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                getProductOptions();
            }
        });
    }
    protected void getProductOptions() {

        ProductItem productItem = (ProductItem) itemListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("\nProduction Item: " + productItem.getProductName());
        String optionName ="";
        String optionId = "";
        OptionItem optionItem = new OptionItem(optionName, optionId);
        optionData.clear();

        if(productItem.getProductId().equals("001")){
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option1a","a001");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option2a","a002");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
        }
        if(productItem.getProductId().equals("002")){
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option1b","b001");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option2b","b002");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option3b","b003");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
        }
        if(productItem.getProductId().equals("003")){
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option1c","c001");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
            optionItem = new OptionItem("option2c","c002");
            optionData.add(optionItem);
        }

        optionView.getItems().setAll(optionData);

        optionView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

        optionView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<OptionItem>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends OptionItem> observableValue, OptionItem optionItem, OptionItem t1) {
                if(t1 != null) {
                    System.out.println("Selected: " + t1.getOptionName());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you select a single item in the Table and the 1st option on the option list you get this output.

```
Production Item: item1
Selected: option1a
```

If you click on a 2nd item in the table and select the 2nd option on the option list you get this output.

```
Production Item: item3
Selected: option2c
Selected: option2c
```

Clicking on a 3rd item and selecting option 2 on the option list gives you this.

```
Production Item: item1
Selected: option2a
Selected: option2a
Selected: option2a
```

How do I get it so that I only get a single result no matter how many items I select something on the product table? Is it possible to do this? Is there a better way of doing this?

I can supply the Constructors and fxml file etc. if needed.

Comment: Every time you make a selection in `itemListView`, you add another, identical listener to `optionView`. When a selection is made in `optionView`, all of the listeners are invoked. Do you only want to add a single listener to `optionView`?

Comment: This sounds like something where you should filter the data of the second table.

Comment: Also, how is the data structured? I would have a list of `OptionItem` associated with each `ProductItem`.  I would then load that list to the second table when one of the `ProductItem` is selected.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that I do only want a single listener for optionView but I'm not sure how to do that. As well, there could be further lists below the option list depending on circumstances. My concern is creating a burden on memory as there could be a couple of thousand items in the production list.

Comment: The data is structures in 2 lists. Selecting an item in the first list calls up a second list which shows all of the options available for the selected item.